# how to install both qt5-qmake and qt4-qmake

Tags: ppa, qt

There is no qt5-qmake on default LTS 12.04 repository so I am using ppa from ubuntu-sdk-team `ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa`

However since this or previous month, it stopped working to me. Now when I try to install both qt5-qmake qt4-qmake I get in some unresolvable dependency conflicts.

Is there any way to simply install both?

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you using?

Comment: LTS 12.04 as in post

Comment: I've just post an answer in <http://askubuntu.com/a/593765/286232> that may be useful there too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I could not find a reliable way though some say that qtchooser works but it doesn't work.
What I do as a workaround is to install `qt4` at first then install qt5, to revert back to qt4 just remove `qt5-default`, it will use qt4. To switch back to `qt5` just install `qt5-default`. It's a tiny deb package lower than 500kb.

EDIT: 
When you attepted to remove qt5-default it will automatically install qt4-default

EDIT2: 
What I did yesterday to use latest version of qmake, I downloaded 32 bit offline installer from http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.2/5.2.1/qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.2.1.run then set executable flag and installed it to `/home/$USER/Qt5.2.1`, it doesn't install it into system path. To use qmake to create makefile you need to specify the path`/home/$USER/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/gcc/bin/qmake -Wall ../project.pro` worked for me

EDIT3: I found an easier way to switch between **qt4** and **qt5** using environment variables

To switch to **qt4**

```
 export QTCHOOSER_RUNTOOL=qtconfig
 export QT_SELECT=4
```

EDIT4:

As I get experienced about programming I come across more simple solutions.

You don't need to switch  between **QT4** <-> **QT5** at all.

Install **QT4** and **QT5** packages from Ubuntu repositories and then locate qmake

```
locate qmake
```

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.3 32 bit so my qmake paths are:

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake
```

All you can do to build your project is to run

for qt4:

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake
```

or for qt5:

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake
```

in your source directory where project*.pro file exist.

Then to compile it with `make` command.

Comment: yes I forgot about Qt installer, that works

Comment: Wish there were a little more information here about which components to install.

Comment: How do I use this without .pro file?? I try this and get .... Usage: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake [mode] [options] [files]

QMake has two modes, one mode for generating project files based on
some heuristics, and the other for generating makefiles. Normally you
shouldn't need to specify a mode, as makefile generation is the default
mode for qmake, but you may use this to test qmake on an existing project.........

Comment: @PatrickMutwiri To create .pro file you  need to run `qmake -project ` then `qmake -makefile`. Check out `qmake --help` In your case it's 
 `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake -project`