# Ubuntu Qmake is not an executable

Tags: 14.04, qt, qt-creator, qt5

I have the latest versions of `qtcreator`, `qt5-qmake` `build-essential` and `g++` installed.

In option of `Build & Run` and choose qmake in `/usr/bin/qmake` I get this error:

```
The qmake executable /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake could not be added: qmake '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake' is not an executable.
```

In Home system I don't have any problem after installing those packages and setting Qmake in option

Other information:

```
tux-world@alachiq:~ > apt-cache search qt5-qmake
qt5-qmake - Qt 5 qmake Makefile generator tool

tux-world@alachiq:~ > ldd /opt/qtForArm/bin/qmake 
     ldd: /opt/qtForArm/bin/qmake: No such file or directory

tux-world@alachiq:~ > sudo chmod +x /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake
[sudo] password for tux-world: 
chmod: cannot access ‘/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: what is the output of `ls -l /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake` ?

Comment: @kenn `ls: cannot access /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake: No such file or directory`

Comment: you installed qt5, why are you trying to execute qt4?

Comment: check out my old answer here http://askubuntu.com/questions/424161/how-to-install-both-qt5-qmake-and-qt4-qmake/424198#424198

Answer (score 1):

If it may be useful:

To have the developer versions of Qt4 and Qt5 at the same time, and to develop using one or the other:

First I downloaded the Qt 5.4.1 offline installer from http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/, I executed it and it was installed in its default folder (in `$HOME/Qt5.4.1`).

To achieve that the system used that Qt 5 version as the default to develop with Qt (and so that it could find the correct `qmake`, etc.), I executed:

```
newQtchooserFolder="$HOME/.config/qtchooser"
mkdir -p "$newQtchooserFolder"
newQt5Configuration="$newQtchooserFolder/5.conf"
echo "$HOME/Qt5.4.1/5.4/gcc_64/bin" > "$newQt5Configuration"
echo "$HOME/Qt5.4.1/5.4/gcc_64/lib" >> "$newQt5Configuration"
sudo ln -sfv "$newQt5Configuration" /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt-default/qtchooser/default.conf
```

And if Qt 4 was needed to develop:

a) Temporarily: `qmake -qt4` (or `qmake -qt=4`) could be executed instead of just `qmake`; or `export QT_SELECT=4` could be executed and then `qmake`.

b) Permanently: The link `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt-default/qtchooser/default.conf` could point to another `.conf` file like `/usr/share/qtchooser/qt4-x86_64-linux-gnu.conf`.

There's more information about those steps in `man qtchooser` and in http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/7.4/general/qtchooser.html.

Answer (score 0):

you can install it from here http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.3/5.3.1/

It appears to be you have 32 bit Ubuntu. So pick up this one http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.3/5.3.1/qt-opensource-linux-x86-5.3.1.run download it then set executable flag and install it to /home/$USER/5.3.1

To use qmake to create makefile you need to specify the path,  run it like

```
 /home/$USER/Qt5.3.1/5.3.1/gcc/bin/qmake -Wall project.pro
```

then it will add all the libraries from new installation.